# Do mangakas have long work hours?

Tags: japan, work, employment

I've found several sources that explain that [mangakas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mangaka) (manga artists) have to work insanely long hours to meet their deadlines.

In this [Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-life-like-as-a-manga-artist), an assistant mangaka claims:

> We were well-paid, but worked 16-hour days , about 20-25 days per month.

On the same page, another answerer says

> The life of mangaka is basically non-stop working: about 14-15 hours every day in drawing, very popular mangakas sleeping about 3-4 hours of a day and have several hours of a week free time.

[This blog article](http://blog.honeyfeed.fm/the-insane-work-schedules-of-your-favorite-manga-artists/) quotes the schedules for several mangaka of highly successful manga series.

> Oda only sleeps 3 hours a day.

[...]

> Here's the time schedule of Kishimoto when he was writing Naruto. On his inking days, the time spent on his desk totalled 19 hours a day.

From personal experience of working over 55 hours in a week, I find the claim to be unlikely.

Is this the the usual amount of work mangakas have to do in order to meet their deadlines?

Comment: What sort of evidence would you find convincing (in either direction)? I am not sure if we will find more reliable sources for this than blogs.

Comment: At least 3 interviews signed by the author of the interview in some magazine where a "principal" mangaka (a mangaka that with a quick search on the internet can be checked that's a mangaka in any major web page dedicated, at least partially, to manga) states about his schedule, or a video interviewing at least 3 "principal" mangakas where that "principal" mangaka can be seen and states the same, or a total of 3 instances of any of the previous things, is convincing enough for me.

Comment: Three hours of sleep sounds unsustainably low - and keeping your employees in constant sleep deprivation is a horrible way to extract the maximum productivity out of them, even if you ignore the ethics side of things.

Comment: @JanDvorak I really hesitate to say this because it may sound uninformedly racist but there’s a lot about the Japanese work ethic that surprises non-Japanese. The question could justifiably be extended to, “do Japanese people in general work insane hours?”